# PostgreSQL: different output for timestamp without time zone depending on client

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I'm puzzled by my PostgreSQL database returning different results for a `timestamp(0) without time zone` field. Let's say I have a table `t`

```
create table t (
    x timestamp(0) without time zone
);
insert into t select now();
```

Now when I run `select * from t` from different clients, I get different outputs.

- **PSQL:** `2014-04-06 10:22:57`
- **JDBC:** `2014-04-06 10:22:57:000` 
   *(driver postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar run through the [SQLExplorer eclipse plugin](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/))*
- **node-pg:** `Sun Apr 06 2014 10:22:57 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

Of the three, only PSQL is the output I expected (and require). Why is this happening, and how can I fix it without having to explicitly cast in the query?

Comment: `timestamp`s are stored without any format in the database. The formatting is always done by the application *displaying* the data. Usually you can configure the SQL client to apply a specific format to `timestamp` (and `date`) columns. As long as you retrieve a real `java.sql.Timestamp` instance from the result set (e.g.  using `ResultSet.getTimestamp()`) this client formatting does not matter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, I just wasn't expecting node-pg to parse it into `Data` object - I was expecting the raw string value. Read the docs, right? I'll just override the type parser. You don't by any chance know of a way to do that per connection or even per query?

Comment: I don't know node-pg so I don't know what a `Data` object is. But the output seems to be the result of calling `toString()` on a `java.sql.Timestamp` instance. Are you by any chance simply calling `System.out.println()` with an Object obtained from a `ResultSet`. If yes, then everything seems OK. Just work with the `java.sql.Timestamp` instance.

Comment: My bad, typo. I meant `Date`. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not using Java, the JDBC is just for an Eclipse plugin I'm using. I'm on JavaScript (node.js)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a particular string format for a timestamp to be returned by the database, you should generally request it in your queries.

```
to_char(the_timestamp_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

See [`to_char` in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

Alternately, you can use the client application language's features to format the timestamp as you desire. This is usually the better option for more feature rich languages.

While PostgreSQL usually returns a specific text format for dates over the query protocol, clients are free to choose to use the binary protocol instead, in which case they'll get a wide integer value in epoch seconds. Rather than relying on the value in the PostgreSQL protocol being formatted how you want, it's much better to ask for exactly what you require.

Comment: That will be exceedingly difficult, because I'm querying generically for syncing: I have a table `journal` which holds changes to the database in the form `sequence number|table_name|row|operation` and based on that I'm building queries dynamically. So manipulating the queries would require a ton of code overhead.

Comment: You'll have to do it client-side by data type, then. Relying on the protocol format is really not wise.

Comment: Why do you consider it unwise?

Comment: See the last par of the answer. You're also dependent on what the client driver does. Beyond me why you don't just format dates client-side.

Comment: Because my synchronization algorithm is abstracted over the type of the data. It basically just reads the data as indicated by the journal and JSONs it to an Android app, where it gets written to the app's database. It's two way syncing, so the algorithms are basically mirror images of each other. Neither one lends itself easily to post processing the data.

Comment: For the sake of clarification, the actual issue - weird formatting - proved solvable by overriding the default node-pg type parser to keep it from parsing into a `Date` object. However, I'm reading your answer and comments - perhaps incorrectly - to be saying this isn't a good idea, and am trying to understand why. Is it because other clients accessing the Postgresql database might choose the binary format and break, or because the output Postgresql produces for the string representation might change in future versions?

Comment: Other clients would not be a problem, because the sole way of accessing the database is through my own web service, so I have full control. And the string representation for timestamps is part of the SQL standard, so it seems unlikely that will change. Or am I missing something else? I'm not trying to be obstinate, just trying to understand.

Comment: What I'd do: When I see a `Date` object (as parsed out by node.js), I'd format it into my desired format. This can be done by walking the results, so long as you can dynamically query objects for type you don't need to know anything about the data. Yes, that means another conversion, but it's a fair bit more future proof. If PostgreSQL changes the wire format for dates, your app won't mysteriously break when you update PostgreSQL and the Pg driver.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean. I'll look into that. Thank you for your suggestions and patience! :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the database representation to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.  Period.  It doesn't change the storage, it adds precision.  Without the time zone, the precision of TIMESTAMP is +/- 24 hours.

Comment: precision? why the hell I would store timezone data, then how should I display to users in a different timezone?

Comment: I prefer sending/storing utc until the date needs to be displayed to the user

Comment: If you know it's UTC, why don't you tell the database about it?

Comment: sending non utc date without time zone information is not an option, it's wrong, I suppose "without timezone" would only mean UTC